# How to get importance sampling weight or likelihood ratio in importance sampling when applied to real world applications?

Tags: markov-process, reinforcement-learning, importance-sampling

When importance sampling is applied to real world applications like robotics control? The target policy $\pi_{(a|s)}$ is not known. So how can we compute the sampling ratio $\pi_{(a_t|s_t)}/\mu{(a_t|s_t)}$? I don't quite understand how importance sampling works when the numerator of the sampling ratio is not known. Can someone show me a concrete example?